Internal CA SAN cert - extra DNS records not showing once cert created
I have an RDS session host fronted by a connection broker (no gateway), used by internal company users.  The farm DNS name is, let's say, farm.domain.local.  Each session host's IP also carries farm.domain.local as an A record for round-robin load balancing.  (More session hosts will be added, just working with one now for simplicity.)
When users RDP to farm.domain.local, they get this common warning pop-up that "the server name on the certificate is incorrect".
To rectify that, I'm trying to create a SAN cert on a domain member server from the internal certification authority server.
I request a cert with the ‘Subject name’ set to CN=servername, and the ‘Alternative name’ set to DNS>sessionhost, DNS>sessionhost.domain.local, DNS>farm, DNS>farm.domain.local. The cert gets issued fine, but then it only shows the single Subject Alternative Name entry of ‘DNS Name =servername.domain.local’. I retried it a few times, same each time. Why doesn’t it keep my multiple DNS entries? Here’s how I create it vs how it comes out.enter image description here
enter image description here
(ignore the 'cnamealias' labels; no cnames involved, that was mislabeled.)
I'd like the cert to keep the multiple DNS entries as a SAN certificate reportedly should.

Two images are identical.

For friendly (DNS) names you would have SAN values "DNS Name=servername.domain.local" however if the value is not a name, but an IP, pretty sure you would have to use "IP Address=10.20.30.40" format when adding.  Depending on how you are creating the CSR it's usually a drop-down list and you can choose what type of SAN it is.  Maybe you did this, but mentioning just in case not.
